# Expressing a multivarible function as ∇ϕ

Tags: calculus, geometry

Show that $g(x,y,z)=(yz^2 +3, xz^2 +2z+1, 2xyz+2y)$ can be expressed as $∇ϕ$ for a function $ϕ$ and find $ϕ$. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're given
$$
g(x,y,z)=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
yz^2 +3\\
xz^2 +2z+1\\
 2xyz+2y
\end{array}
\right]
$$
We know that the gradient of a scalar $\phi$ is given by
$$
\nabla\phi(x,y,z)=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\phi_x \\
\phi_y \\
\phi_z
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Setting these equal to each other gives three equations
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\phi_x &=& yz^2 +3\\
\phi_y &=& xz^2 +2z+1\\
\phi_z &=&  2xyz+2y\\
\end{array}
$$
To solve this system, we'll integrate each equation while holding the other two variables constant; this is like "undoing" the partial derivative, and note that we can only calculate these integrals to within an unknown function of the other two variables.
$$
\phi = \int\phi_x\;dx = xyz^2 + 3x + a(y,z)
$$
$$
\phi = \int\phi_y\;dy = xyz^2 +2yz+y + b(x,z)
$$
$$
\phi = \int\phi_z\;dz = xyz^2+2yz + c(x,y) \\
$$
Now we have to find the unknown functions $a,b,c$. All three expressions for $\phi$ must yield the same answer, so we use those functions to match the terms that are kind of "missing" between the expressions. By inspection then, we can see if
$$
a(y,z)=y+2yz
$$
$$
b(x,z)=3x
$$
$$
c(x,y)=3x+y
$$
Then 
$$
\phi=xyz^2 + 3x + y + 2yz
$$
The answers for $a,b,c$ were of course still only good to within an arbitrary constant / boundary value, so the actual final answer is
$$
\fbox{$\phi(x,y,z)=xyz^2 + 3x + y + 2yz + C$}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- If $\vec{g} = \nabla \phi$, then it must hold: $g_1 = \phi_x , \ g_2 = \phi_y, \ g_3 = \phi_z$, where $g_i$ is the $i$ component of $g$.
- Use the first of the equations, for example, $g_1 = \phi_x$ in order to obtain a first integral for $\phi$:

$$\phi(x,y,z) = xyz^2 + 3x + f(y,z),$$

for some function $f(y,z)$.

- Use the other two relations to conclude that:

$$\phi(x,y,z) = xyz^2 + 3x + 2yz+ y.$$

$\phi$ is said to be the potential function. More precisely, you should add an adition constant, $\phi \to \phi + K$ making the potential "undetermined", not so for the potential difference between two points (this is quite useful in a lot of fields of physics).

Cheers!

**Edit**

In order to show that $\vec{g}$ can be expressed as the gradient of a potential, you firstly should show that $\nabla \times  \vec{g} = (0,0,0)$.